# Why doesn't checking an attribute's value imply that the attribute exists?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

While using `BeautifulSoup` I very often have to condition some action on the value of a tag's class. For example, imagine that I want to do some action on `<p>` only when the attribute is `class="box"`, and a different action otherwise.
What I do is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<html><body>
<h1>Titolo</h1>
<p>Testo che sta sotto il titolo</p>
<p class="sidenote">Questo da stampare</p>
<p>Questo è il testo della nota marginale</p>
</body></html>
''',"lxml")

for sel in soup.body:
    if not isinstance(sel,NavigableString) and \
       "class" in sel.attrs and "sidenote" in sel["class"]:
        print(sel)
    else
        print("not found")
```

This is a bit clumsy. I wonder if there's a way to make the condition a little more compact than this. The ideal would be that a check on the final condition (that `class` contains `sidenote`) implied that the element does have a `class` attribute and, consequently, it is a tag, not a NavigableString.

Comment: What makes you think the `and` version doesn't work? Post a [mcve]. It should have worked; you likely introduced some other error you didn't notice.

Comment: You were right, the problem was that the element was a NavigableString, and I need to check this first. However, my doubt remains at least in part: why isn't it possible to check "implicitly" the existence of the attribute?

Comment: You can use `soup.body.find_all()` which returns only tags (no `NavigableString` objects). Then use `sel.get("class", [])` as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ternary operator would definitely remove some bulk, though not everything at once. The number of if-else's would still be same though. So, not sure if that would work for you.

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

So the current code would become:

```
if "class" in div.attrs:
   div.do_something if "box" in div["class"] else div.do_something_else
else:
   div.do_something_else
```

or if you want to compress it further (though I feel that would affect readability):

```
(div.do_something if "box" in div["class"] else div.do_something_else) if "class" in div.attrs else div.do_something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

Like for Python dictionaries, you can use the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method instead of accessing the element using `[...]`. This way, it does not raise a `KeyError` if the element is not present but just returns `None`. Also, you can provide a default value, so you can simplify the code to:

```
for sel in soup.body:
    if not isinstance(sel,NavigableString) and \
           "sidenote" in sel.get("class", []):
        print(sel)
    else
        print("not found")
```